# How can I add a row to a GWT CellTable from within the onSuccess function of an AsyncCallback?

Tags: gwt

I created a CellTable with contacts. Some of the contacts are already filled into the table by the client. In the onModuleLoad function an additional Contact object is requested. Now I'd like to add another row to the table

In the function onModuleLoad I added the table widget, in the onSuccess I would like to add a new data row to the table with the received contact:

```
List<Contact> cList = getKnownContacts();
CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>();
final ListDataProvider<Contact> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Contact>();
dataProvider.setList(cList);
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);

// Create name column.
TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(Contact contact) {
        return contact.getName();
    }
};

// Create address column.
TextColumn<Contact> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(Contact contact) {
        return contact.getAddress();
    }
};

table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Address");

RootPanel.get().add(table);

contactService.getContactById(1234,
    new AsyncCallback<Contact>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            ...
        }

        public void onSuccess(Contact result) {
            // add row to table???
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the execution of `dataProvider.getList().add(result);` threw an exception because the "add" function was not supported on the list. I assume the reason for that was that the `dataProvider` is `final`. Here the solution:

```
List<Contact> newList = new ArrayList<Contact>(dataProvider.getList());
newList.add(result);
dataProvider.refresh();
```

Comment: The DataProvider is not final, but maybe you were using a list that does not support adding items (e.g. an unmodifiable list, as returned by `Collections.unmodifiableList(list);`).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call:

```
cList.add(result);
```

Comment: better use `dataProvider.getList().add(result);` `dataProvider.refresh()` is not needed in this case. Also, I think keeping the list as a separate object is not a really good idea (just my opinion here). You should just keep it in the dataProvider, and if/when you need it just get it from there.

Comment: @francescoforesti: You are right about refresh(). I did not understand the comment about list - there is only one list object in the OP example. DataProvider is only given a pointer to this list.

Comment: I already tried that. `cList.add(result);` doesn't work, because it would need to be `final` that I'm allowed to use it in the function `onSuccess`. Same for the `dataProvider.getList().add(result);`. When adding the result I get an exception.

Comment: The message of the exception is: "Add not supported on this list"

Comment: Thank's for your contributions, I figured out what was wrong (see answer below)